# How to configure inherited packages in the go.mod file

Tags: go

My project has three modules, the file directory is (/main.go) (/b/b.go) (/a/a.go).and the go.mod  as follows

```
<-- /main.go-->:
package main    
import (
    "b.com/b"
)
...
<-- /go.mod-->
module main
go 1.16
require b.com/b v0.0.0
replace b.com/b => ./b

<-- /b/go.mod-->
module main
go 1.16
require a.com/a v0.0.0
replace a.com/a => ../a
```

In the file (/b/go.mod), if I write:

```
require a.com/a v0.0.0
replace a.com/a => ../a
```

it will show in (/main.go) that "b.com/b" cannot be imported. If not , the program is normal,What's wrong here?

Comment: 1. There are no "inherited packages". 2. "My project has three modules" together with lots of replace directives hints at a misuse of modules. Are you sure you need three modules? 3. The module in the folder b declares itself to be named "main" but you import is as "b.com/b". You really should get your naming straight. I'd suggest putting everything under _one_ module, using a descriptive name for that module like "my.playground/firstexample".

Comment: Do not create go.mod if one of the parent folders already has go.mod. Put them on the same level or below single go.mod. (e.g. your root folder will be ./cmd/main.go ./a/a.go ./b/b.go ./go.mod ./go.sum)

Answer (score 0):

First, make your module at the top level:

```
go mod init stackoverflow.com/user/repo
```

Then make `pack/pack.go`:

```
package pack

const Pack = 1
```

Then make `main.go`:

```
package main
import "stackoverflow.com/user/repo/pack"

func main() {
   println(pack.Pack)
}
```

Then build:

```
go build
```